# How to prove $ 1 \geq \int_{0}^{1} x \cot x \, \mathrm{d}x $?

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to prove

$$ 1 \geq \int_{0}^{1} x \cot x \, \mathrm{d}x, $$

and I can prove $x \cot x \leq 1$. Can I say $f(x) = x \cot x$ and $g(x)=1$ and $f(x) \leq g(x)$ hence $\int f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \leq \int g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 1$?

Is that correct? If it is a theorem, what is the name?

Comment: The argument is valid by the monotonicity of the integral

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Inequalities In particular the part *Inequalities between functions*.

Comment: I would say it's called positivity of Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @WhatsUp Well sure, but it's provable for the Riemann integral without measure theory so I figured that's the result I should quote.